# How to create apache rewrite rule for unique header?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to denay access to my site from anyone that doesn't have key=123 in the request heder. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a specific key’s value in your query string, you can check for its existence with a RewriteCond statement:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !key=  

RewriteRule ^/?script_that_requires_key.php$ other_script_when no key.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I dont want to use query string. I want to check only the header and find the key=somevalue is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have access to the httpd.conf or the .htaccess file.

In this example, I'll assume you'll be editing the .htaccess file.  In this case, you will be adding to the directory you are protecting:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
SetEnvIf key "^123$" AllowHeader
Allow from env=AllowHeader
```

- "Order deny,allow" will deny all unless it matches one of the "Allow" directives
- "Deny from all" is the explicit command to "Deny from all"
- The third line makes use of the mod_setenvif module and checks if the header with the name "key" has the value "^123$".  "^123$" is a regular expression so that a header with the exact value "123" will be matched, and an environment variable "AllowHeader" will be set.
- The request is allowed through if the environment variable "AllowHeader" is found.